# Does the convention of “F. Last” have any legal significance?

Tags: legal-terms, legal-history

I’ve noticed that legal correspondence sometimes addresses folks in the format of F. Last where F. Is the addressee’s first initial, and Last is their complete last name. What is the origin of this convention, and does it have any current or historical legal significance?

Comment: That form is pretty common, and certainly not restricted to legal documents. Are you asking where the custom of abbreviating names like that came from? That seems like a better question for [history.se].

Comment: Perhaps, I thought perhaps even ELL.SX. But I think the appropriateness of potential migration  depends somewhat on the answer that it receives here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it have any current or historical legal significance

It does not, and I can find no evidence suggesting that this is a convention or that it occurs more frequently in legal correspondence than otherwise. I know some *courts* refer to counsel at the outset of written reasons in this manner, but that is merely a style choice. That choice varies between courts across Canada and even within the same court.

Comment: I agree. There is a convention in legal citation to include only the surnames of the parties when referring to cited cases but that omits the first letter of the given name entirely. In litigation where everyone or most parties have the same surname, the common solution is to refer to parties by the first names after formally apologizing for the informality necessitated by the circumstances.